# How do I make object to update its value, based on other objects value change, in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to make basic neural network simulation. It consists of Neurons and NeuronConnections. In code below, the value of neuron2, should change whenever value of neuron1 is updated:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Neuron neuron1 = new Neuron();
        Neuron neuron2 = new Neuron();

        NeuronConnection neuronConnection = new NeuronConnection(neuron1, neuron2);

        neuron1.addInput(20);
        System.out.println(neuron2.getOutput());
    }
}
```

For now, I get just "0" which is default value.

Here is code for Neuron and NeuronConncetion objects:

```
public class Neuron {
    private double output;
    private List<Double> inputArray;

    public Neuron() {
        output = 0;
        inputArray = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public Neuron (double input) {
        inputArray = new LinkedList<>();
        inputArray.add(input);
        output += input;
    }

    public void addInput(double input) {
        inputArray.add(input);
        output += input;
    }

    public void addMultipleInputs(List<Double> inputs) {
        inputArray.addAll(inputs);
        for (double input: inputs) {
            output += input;
        }
    }

    public double getOutput() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

```
public class NeuronConnection {
    private double weight;
    private Neuron inNeuron;
    private Neuron outNeuron;
    private double outValue;

    public NeuronConnection(Neuron inNeuron, Neuron outNeuron) {
        this.inNeuron = inNeuron;
        this.outNeuron = outNeuron;
        weight = Math.random();
        outValue = inNeuron.getOutput()*weight;
        outNeuron.addInput(outValue);
    }

    public double getOutValue() {
        return outValue;
    }
}
```

**The questions is**: How do I make neuron2 change its value, whenever I change input of neuron1?

Comment: If you want something to happen when you call the `addInput` method, then you need to write some code to make it happen, and that code should go in the `addInput` method.

Comment: okay, at first I've misunderstood your question....your whole design is flawed...change is one neuron triggers other neuron to chnage,..but you din;t design the code to do so...

Comment: Familiarize yourself with Observer Pattern where neuron2 listens for changes from neuron1. For example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern

Comment: Yes, the question is how do I make it? Because I don't have the proper knowledge.

Comment: @drodil, he is a newb..I don't think (s)he would be familiar with observer pattern...

Comment: @reyad exactly, (s)he should get to know it to implement this kind of things properly.

Comment: @pkonopacki, I would suggest you try to solve the problem yourself, you'll learn a lot, to solve the problem you dont need to know observer pattern(for now, you can learn it later), if u can't solve this yourself, its better to consult with friends and teachers...it'll help you better than SO...

Comment: This actually answers my question, I did not know about observer pattern. Thank you.

Comment: @drodil, yes, I agree to that. But, it seems, (s)he is complete newb...I just can't tell someone who just learned coding(and didn't develop any proper algorithmic/ds knowledge) to learn observer pattern...

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you a simple solution. You just have to keep a reference to `NeuronConnection` in `Neuron` class and add a method setConnection() and call `NeuronConnection's update() method`(which we'll add later in `NeuronConnection`) from `addInput()` or `addMultipleInputs()` method of `Neuron class`. The new design of `Neuron` class:

```
public class Neuron {
    private NeuronConnection conn;
    private double output;
    private List<Double> inputArray;

    public Neuron() {
        output = 0;
        inputArray = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public Neuron (double input) {
        inputArray = new LinkedList<>();
        inputArray.add(input);
        output += input;
    }

    public void addInput(double input) {
        inputArray.add(input);
        output += input;
        conn.update();
    }

    public void addMultipleInputs(List<Double> inputs) {
        inputArray.addAll(inputs);
        for (double input: inputs) {
            output += input;
        }
        conn.update();
    }

    public double getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    // i've added this method
    public void setConnection(NeuronConnection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }
}
```

Now, redesign your `NeuronConnection` class:

```
public class NeuronConnection {
    private double weight;
    private Neuron inNeuron;
    private Neuron outNeuron;
    private double outValue;

    public NeuronConnection(Neuron inNeuron, Neuron outNeuron) {
        this.inNeuron = inNeuron;
        this.outNeuron = outNeuron;

        // now, setConnection
        this.inNeuron.setConnection(this);
        this.outNeuron.setConnection(this);

        weight = Math.random();
        outValue = inNeuron.getOutput()*weight;
        outNeuron.addInput(outValue);
    }

    public double getOutValue() {
        return outValue;
    }

    // i've added this
    public void update() {
      // this calculation is little flawed
      // you've to edit/fix this as you think it will be
      // perfect for your neural network
      outValue = inNeuron.getOutput() * weight;
      outNeuron.addInput(outValue);
    }
}
```

Now, the Main class, there's no change...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Neuron neuron1 = new Neuron();
        Neuron neuron2 = new Neuron();

        NeuronConnection neuronConnection = new NeuronConnection(neuron1, neuron2);

        neuron1.addInput(20);
        System.out.println(neuron2.getOutput());
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should get you on the right track...

Let me know, if you've any question...